# basic d3js data update

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Please take a look at the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBf9y/).
It updates the data when you click the button. One thing that I don't get is the purpose of doing `bar.exit().remove()`in draw() function.

```
function draw(data) {
    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 50])
        .range([0, 100]);

    var bars = d3.select("#work_queues_chart")
        .selectAll("div")
        .attr("id","work_queues_chart")
        .data(data);

    // enter selection
    bars
        .enter().append("div");

    // update selection
    bars
        .style("width", function (d) {return scale(d) + "%";})
        .text(function (d) {return d;});

    // exit selection
    bars
        .exit().remove();
};
```

Does it remove the old data that was there before entering the new data? If so, shouldn't it be called before `setting bars.data(data)`? Any enlightment will be appreciated!

**update:**

```
    function draw(data) {
        var bars = d3.select("body")
          .selectAll("div")
          .data(data);
        var charts = bars
          .enter().append("div")
          .attr("class", "bar")
        charts
          .selectAll("button")
          .append("button")
          .text(function (d) { 
            console.log(d)
            return d.name; })
          .attr("class", "my-button")
        bars
          .style("width", function (d) {return d.val*10 + "px";})
          .text(function (d) {
            return d.name; });
        bars
          .exit().remove();
    };
```

I got the update part working, but now the buttons are not appended correctly. Is there anything wrong with how I append the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

In your case `bars.exit().remove()` is doing nothing. But if the updated data was an array of less than 6 elements, say 4 elements, then `bars.exit()` would return a selection of the 2 DOM nodes that don't have corresponding data, and `.remove()` would remove them. Which is what you'd want in that case.

Comment: That makes sense! Then how do I update values of the existing array? Say, the initial array has [1,2,3,4,5] and I want it to have [4,4,4,4,4] and graph it.

Comment: You already have that working, no? It's taken care of by the block you labeled `// update selection`

Comment: could you take a look at my updated code and see what I am doing wrong about appending button elements for each bar graph?

Comment: Take out the line `.selectAll("button")`